# How to use custom pagination in Gijgo Grid using jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller, gijgo-grid

I am using the Gijgo grid in my MVC application each time I loaded the grid it needs a total count of records to show **Displaying records 1-100 of 100000.**
To get the total count each time takes a lot of time that impacts the performance of the application and sometimes leads to time-out exceptions.
I am looking for a way to implement the pagination without needing the total count of data and it would look something like this:

**1,2,3...Next**

but I am not able to find anything yet. Please help me out with that.

Note:- I have to achieve this using the **Gijgo** grid because it is implemented in the application everywhere. To change it to another grid would increase the cost that we do not want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with pager.leftControls and pager.rightControls configuration settings. You can see an example about that at https://gijgo.com/grid/configuration/pager.leftControls